# Can I get a `du` grouped by month?

Tags: shell, files, disk-usage

I have a directory with a lot of photos in it. Specifically, `du -sh --apparent-size /path/to/myfolder` gives me 331G. Which is great. But now I want to get a listing grouped by month, e.g. something like this:

```
2016-01   20MB
2016-02  520MB
2016-03  312MB
...
```

Is there a (reasonable) way to do this with linux builtins, or should I just write my own Python utility to do it?

Comment: Linux doesn't have _builtins_, it's an operating system kernel. Do you mean _with the commands found by default in some Linux based operating system (like Debian, Fedora, ChromeOS...)_ instead?

Comment: The Linux kernel is the linux kernel, and if I meant linux kernel builtins I would've said that. If you *must* be pedantic, I mean the general set of tools that you're statistically likely to have installed with a default installation of any of the top 5 linux distros.

Comment: @WayneWerner In other words, you mean GNU/Linux, including Bash, Coreutils, and other core components of the GNU operating environment. #rmswasright

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On linux, try:

```
find /my/path -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm %s\n' | awk '{b[$1]+=$2} END{for (date in b) print date, b[date]}' | sort
```

#### How it works

- `find /my/path`

  This looks for files in in /my/path.
- `-maxdepth 1`

  This tells `find` not to look into subdirectories.  (If you want a recursive search, then omit this option.)
- `-type f`

  This tells `find` to limit the search to regular files.
- `-printf '%TY-%Tm %s\n'`

  This tells `find` to print out year-month followed by the size in bytes for each file.

  Since we have no use for them, the names of the files found are not printed.
- `b[$1]+=$2`

  For each file found, we add its byte count, found from column 2, to the count that that year-month combination in associative array `b`.
- `END{for (date in b) print date, b[date]}`

  After we have processed all the output from `find`, we print out the results.
- `sort`

  This sorts the results in date order.

#### Multiple line version

For those who prefer their code spread out over multiple lines:

```
find /my/path -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm %s\n' |
  awk '
    {
      b[$1]+=$2
    }

    END{
      for (date in b)
        print date, b[date]
    }
    ' | sort
```

#### Example

Let's consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls -l
total 27816
-rw------- 1 john1024 john1024 2459173 Nov 23  2015 img100.jpg
-rw------- 1 john1024 john1024 3479750 Nov 23  2015 img101.jpg
-rw------- 1 john1024 john1024 4028939 Nov 23  2015 img102.jpg
-rw------- 1 john1024 john1024 2928519 Jul 30 18:55 img103.jpg
-rw------- 1 john1024 john1024 2948294 Jul 30 18:55 img104.jpg
-rw------- 1 john1024 john1024 3177583 Aug  1 16:56 img105.jpg
-rw-rw---- 1 john1024 john1024 3111737 Apr 18  2016 img106.jpg
-rw-rw---- 1 john1024 john1024 1441310 Apr 18  2016 img107.jpg
-rw-rw---- 1 john1024 john1024 2430158 Apr 25 16:26 img108.jpg
-rw-rw---- 1 john1024 john1024 2424504 Apr 25 16:26 img109.jpg
```

The output from our command is:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm %s\n' | awk '{b[$1]+=$2} END{for (date in b) print date, b[date]}' | sort
2015-11 9967862
2016-04 9407709
2016-07 5876813
2016-08 3177583
```

#### Refinements

If we want the output in mebibytes (MiB) instead of bytes, we can convert the units like this:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm %s\n' | awk '{b[$1]+=$2} END{for (date in b) print date, b[date]/1024**2, "MiB"}' | sort
2015-11 9.50609 MiB
2016-04 8.97189 MiB
2016-07 5.60457 MiB
2016-08 3.03038 MiB
```

We can get still more control over output format by using `printf`.  Here, to keep just one digit after the decimal point, we format the size with `%5.1f`:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm %s\n' | awk '{b[$1]+=$2} END{for (date in b) printf "%s %5.1f MiB\n", date, b[date]/1024**2}' | sort
2015-11   9.5 MiB
2016-04   9.0 MiB
2016-07   5.6 MiB
2016-08   3.0 MiB
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Can you recommend any awk tutorials? I've not yet found one that hasn't made my eyes cross within about twenty seconds.

Comment: @hBy2Py My favorite introduction to awk, even though it is now a bit dated, is the [Grymoire tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: i suggest using `printf "%s %9d\n", date, b[date]` instead of `print date, b[date]` to add space padding to second column

Comment: @rav_kr Good idea.  I just updated the answer with an example that uses `printf`.

Comment: FWIW if you have `find` that supports `-maxdepth` you _probably_ have `[g]awk` that supports `PROC_INFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"`

Comment: bytes / 1024 gives KiB. To get Mib i think is `b[date]/1048576**2`.